# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS> system shuts down error: syslog question

Tags: syslog

Computer is shutting down frequently, found this in syslog:

```
Oct 15 17:27:43 d01 systemd[2527]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction for graphical-session.target/stop is destructive (update-notifier-crash.service has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
Oct 15 17:27:43 d01 systemd[1]: Stopping GNOME Display Manager...
Oct 15 18:31:33 d01 systemd-modules-load[607]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

18:31 is the first message after reboot.

Is there anything to understand the cause with reading these last messages?

Comment: Try `CTRL` +`ALT` + `F3` and enter this command: `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

Comment: What is the  meaning?

Comment: Press down Control + Alt + F3 and restart GDM using this command: `sudo sytemctl  restart gdm`